# Can you render this image in css?

Tags: css

Could you please render this red figure in css?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bzON.png)

Comment: Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/geekyquentin/pen/ZEroOWY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```